# Get Environment Variable out of new Process in c#

Tags: c#, .net, process, environment-variables

I have a c# application which spawns a new Process in which a environment variable is set. In the c# application, during the process run, I want to access the variable.

Source code looks like that:

```
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c " + "\"" + "set MYSPECIALENV=someContent & set & pause" + "\"";
        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;

        Console.WriteLine("Starting process");
        p.Start();
        ICollection envVarsSpawnedProcess = p.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables.Keys;

        if (envVarsSpawnedProcess.Cast<string>().Contains("MYSPECIALENV"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Found! :)");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Not found :(");

        }

        p.WaitForExit();
```

This example is somehow simplified since in my real application I execute a command script which set a specific environment dynamically, but this code snippet brings it to the minimum.

The point is that I need to access the environment variable, which was defined in the spawned process, and I need to access it from the c# application.

However, the list of environment variables which I get from the ProcessStartInfo object seems to not reflect the newly created environment variable "mySpecialEnv".

My first doubt was that maybe ProcessStartInfo does not really access the Environment Code Block of the process, but only gets the information from the registry. Can someone confirm this? I googled this quite a long time, but did not find a confirmation...

My second doubt was that I run into race conditions (e.g. I try to access the environment variable too early), but even with implemented polling mechanism I get no better result.

Is this somehow possible to realize with pure .net?
1) Spawn process which creates a new environment variable
2) Access/read this environment variable from the c# application

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2015/09/15/10641604.aspx

Answer (score 0):

after p.start() you need to wait until it finishes the process

and then you need to start another process to check for your environment variable.

```
Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c " + "\"" + "set MYSPECIALENV=someContent & set & pause" + "\"";
    p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;

    Console.WriteLine("Starting process");
    p.Start();
    p.WaitForExit();
    ICollection envVarsSpawnedProcess = p.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables.Keys;

    if (envVarsSpawnedProcess.Cast<string>().Contains("MYSPECIALENV"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Found! :)");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Not found :(");

    }
```

Comment: Can u please explain this a little bit more detailed? What shall my second process do? Did you try out your proposal?